# Why is the `have_field` Capybara matcher returning "no matches" for a hidden field in my rspec tests?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am trying to assert that an `input[type=hidden]` was filled with a value in a Rails request spec, but the Capybara `have_field` matcher returns "no matches" even though when I inspect `response.body` the field is definitely there.

For example, I tried the following:

`expect(response.body).to have_field('after_create_path', with: '/some_path')`

`expect(response.body).to have_field('after_create_path', type: :hidden, with: '/some_path')`

Answer (score 2):

The reason this was failing is that the Capybara made the decision to optimize their matchers for UI **that the user can see**. In other words, they want to focus on integration/feature testing and not the request spec level. `have_field` will not find things that are hidden from the user's view by design.

Here is a comment that sums it up from `jnicklas`:

> Well, pretty much. We don't go out of our way to support stuff which isn't specific to testing stuff which is visible to users. If I'd have my way, things would be more restrictive than they are, but pragmatism gets in the way, as is the case with :visible => false.
>
> As far as checking for hidden fields, as you noticed, it's possible, it just isn't easy, and that's kind of where we draw the line. When someone uses have_field to assert the value of a field in the context of an integration test, then they don't expect that to find hidden fields, and that is the use case we optimize for.
>
> We provide you the power of low level APIs so you can work around these defaults, we even provide you the power to build abstractions using the add_selector API, we just don't optimize for that use case.

I originally found the comment on [this Github issue](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/1017)

Answer (score 0):

As your answer states `have_field` doesn't locate inputs of type 'hidden'.  If you really need/want to test hidden fields it's easy enough to add your own selector type (as `jnicklas` mentioned).  Something like

```
Capybara.add_selector(:hidden_field) do
  visible :hidden
  xpath do |locator|
    xpath = XPath.descendant(:input)[XPath.attr(:type) == 'hidden']
    xpath = xpath[(XPath.attr(:id) == locator) | (XPath.attr(:name) == locator)] if locator
    xpath             
  end
  filter(:with) do |node, with|
    with.is_a?(Regexp) ? node.value =~ with : node.value == with.to_s
  end
end
```

which could then be called via

```
expect(response.body).to have_selector(:hidden_field, 'after_create_path', with: '/some_path')
```